# JavaFX change height of GridPane Row according to a VBox inside it

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have a VBox inside a gridpane's row. I add values inside the VBox programmatically. I want to change the height of my GridPane's row (containing the Vbox) according to the height of VBox.
Any help would be appreciated.
Below is my FXML:

```
    <BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="720.0" prefWidth="1080.0" stylesheets="@Styles.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="ResponsiveHomeController">
   <center>
      <ScrollPane fitToWidth="true" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <content>
            <AnchorPane maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT" prefHeight="693.0" prefWidth="923.0" scaleShape="false" styleClass="center">
               <children>
                  <TextField fx:id="rows" layoutX="217.0" layoutY="117.0" promptText="Rows" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="217.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="117.0" />
                  <TextField fx:id="columns" layoutX="510.0" layoutY="117.0" promptText="Columns" styleClass="normalTF" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="510.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="117.0" />
                  <Button layoutX="400.0" layoutY="192.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#createMatrixPressed" text="Ceate Matrix" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="400.0" />
                  <FlowPane columnHalignment="CENTER" layoutX="108.0" layoutY="266.0" prefHeight="152.0" prefWidth="573.0">
                     <children>
                        <GridPane gridLinesVisible="true" prefHeight="72.0" prefWidth="665.0">
                           <columnConstraints>
                              <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="95.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="66.0" />
                              <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="512.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="512.0" />
                              <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="120.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="87.0" />
                           </columnConstraints>
                           <rowConstraints>
                              <RowConstraints maxHeight="76.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="32.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                              <RowConstraints maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" valignment="CENTER" vgrow="ALWAYS" />
                              <RowConstraints maxHeight="202.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="32.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                           </rowConstraints>
                           <children>
                              <VBox fx:id="supplyVbox" alignment="TOP_CENTER" maxWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="125.0" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                                 <padding>
                                    <Insets left="5.0" right="5.0" />
                                 </padding>
                              </VBox>
                              <Label alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="20.0" prefWidth="481.0" text="Costs" textAlignment="CENTER" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Label>
                              <Label alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="20.0" prefWidth="125.0" text="Supply" textAlignment="CENTER" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Label>
                              <Label alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="20.0" prefWidth="125.0" text="Demand" textAlignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Label>
                              <HBox fx:id="demandHbox" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                              <Label alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="20.0" prefWidth="125.0" text="Suppliers" textAlignment="CENTER">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Label>
                              <VBox fx:id="supplierVbox" alignment="TOP_CENTER" maxWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="66.0" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                                 <padding>
                                    <Insets left="5.0" right="5.0" />
                                 </padding>
                              </VBox>
                              <TextField fx:id="total" promptText="Total" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                              <VBox fx:id="costVbox" alignment="TOP_CENTER" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="512.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.valignment="CENTER" GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS" />
                           </children>
                        </GridPane>
                        <AnchorPane prefHeight="38.0" prefWidth="666.0">
                           <children>
                              <Button layoutX="306.0" layoutY="7.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#createTableButtonPressed" text="Submit" />
                           </children>
                        </AnchorPane>
                        <AnchorPane fx:id="tableAnchorPane" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="40.0" prefHeight="33.0" prefWidth="666.0" style="-fx-border-color: black;" />
                     </children>
                  </FlowPane>
               </children>
               <padding>
                  <Insets bottom="20.0" />
               </padding>
            </AnchorPane>
         </content>
      </ScrollPane>
   </center>
   <top>
      <MenuBar BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <menus>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
        </menus>
      </MenuBar>
   </top>
   <left>
      <AnchorPane styleClass="sideBar">
         <children>
            <VBox layoutY="101.0" prefHeight="593.0" prefWidth="153.0" styleClass="sideBarButton" stylesheets="@Styles.css" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0">
               <children>
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="55.0" prefWidth="153.0" text="LCM" textAlignment="CENTER">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="19.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Button>
               </children>
            </VBox>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </left>
   <right>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="695.0" prefWidth="0.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </right>
</BorderPane>
```

I've set the Vgrow property of gridpan's row to always but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Try removing the `prefHeight` attribute from your `RowConstraints`. If you're using Scene Builder, set the `Pref Height` to `USE_COMPUTED_SIZE`. This will allow JavaFX to determine the appropriate height of the row, based on its children.

Comment: [mcve] please..